# GSON failing to deserialize object it had previously serialized with: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, json, gson

This is a narrow-down example and so nonsensical but demonstrates the problem.

The following code:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.google.gson.*;

class X {}

class SomeType {
    private Map <X,  String> map;
    public SomeType() {
        this.map = new HashMap<X, String>();
        map.put(new X(), "b");
    }
}

public class FooMain {

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String foo = gson.toJson(new SomeType(), SomeType.class);
        System.out.println(foo);                           // line 20
        SomeType st = gson.fromJson(foo, SomeType.class);  // line 21
    }
}
```

fails with:

```
 [java] Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 20
 [java]     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:187)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:146)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:795)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
 [java]     at FooMain.main(FooMain.java:21)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 20
 [java]     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:339)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:322)
 [java]     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
 [java]     ... 10 more
```

whereas line 20 prints:

```
{"map":{"X@185b10b":"b"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gson` serializes a `Map` by using the key as the JSON key and the map element's value as the value. Because your `X` class doesn't have a custom overriden `toString()` method, it uses `Object#toString()` and serializes it as `X@185b10b` but can't deserialize it. It actually wouldn't be able to deserialize it even if you did provide a `toString()`.

I guess you've found an edge case where you cannot serialize everything correctly. The key of a JSON object must be a `String`.

Comment: So, what is one to do in such cases?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Change your design, a key (name) has to be a String. You would need to implement a custom deserializer that can understand the String format of an object and create an `X` object from it.

Comment: I was able to implement that with a custom deserializer however when I tried using a full adapter (`JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer`) so as to "free" the `toString()` method for other purposes , GSON keeps using the `toString()` and disregards the custom serializer for the `Map` key class. Is this your understanding as well? i.e. that you have to use the `toString()` as opposed to being able to use a custom serializer?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I believe it depends at which level you apply the custom deserializer. I believe it should be on the `Map`. Gson defaults to using Strings for the JSON names from the Map keys, that's why you have to modify it so that it serializes it in a String format you can deserialize from.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so thanks to Sotirios Delimanolis answer I found the following:

- you can provide a custom deserializer only for the `Map` key class. In that case the `toString` method of that key class has to provide the "serialization" format

  *or*
- you can provide a generic adapter (serializer + deserializer) for the `Map` class itself, plus a generic adapter (serializer + deserializer) for the `Map` key class. The only advantage of this method is that the `toString` method of the key class can then be used for other purposes and doesn't have to play along with the deserializer.

Following is the complete code for the second case:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

class X {
    public int x;
    public X(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("boo ha ha %d", x);
    }
}

class SomeType {
    private Map <X,  String> map;
    public SomeType() {
        this.map = new HashMap<X, String>();
        map.put(new X(2), "b");
    }
    public String toString() {
        List<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        for (X x : map.keySet())
            rv.add(String.format("%s -> %s\n", x.toString(), map.get(x)));
        return StringUtils.join(rv, "\n");
    }
}

public class FooMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(X.class, new XAdapter());
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Map.class, new MapAdapter());
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.serializeNulls().create();
        SomeType original = new SomeType();
        System.out.println("original is: "+original);
        String foo = gson.toJson(original, SomeType.class);
        System.out.println("JSON form is: "+foo);                     
        SomeType reconstructed = gson.fromJson(foo, SomeType.class);  
        System.out.println("reconstructed is: "+reconstructed);
    }
}


class MapAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Map<?, ?>>, JsonDeserializer<Map<?, ?>> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Map<?, ?> m, Type typeOfT, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray rv = new JsonArray();
        for (Object k : m.keySet()) {
            JsonObject kv = new JsonObject();
            kv.add        ("k"     , context.serialize(k));
            kv.addProperty("ktype" , k.getClass().getName());
            kv.add        ("v"     , context.serialize(m.get(k)));
            kv.addProperty("vtype" , m.get(k).getClass().getName());
            rv.add(kv);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<?, ?> deserialize(JsonElement _json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray json = (JsonArray) _json;
        Map<Object, Object> rv = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < json.size() ; i++) {
            JsonObject o = (JsonObject) json.get(i);
            String ktype = o.getAsJsonPrimitive("ktype").getAsString();
            String vtype = o.getAsJsonPrimitive("vtype").getAsString();
            Class<?> kklass = null;
            Class<?> vklass = null;
            try {
                kklass = Class.forName(ktype);
                vklass = Class.forName(vtype);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new JsonParseException(e.getMessage());
            }
            Object k = context.deserialize( o.get("k"), kklass);
            Object v = context.deserialize( o.get("v"), vklass);
            rv.put(k, v);
        }
        return rv;
    }

}


class XAdapter implements JsonSerializer<X>, JsonDeserializer<X> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(X x, Type typeOfT, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return context.serialize(x.x);
    }

    @Override
    public X deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String s = json.getAsString();
        int x = Integer.valueOf(s);
        return new X(x);
    }
}
```